# How many cards of a single suit must be present in any set of n cards?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a standard deck with 52 cards, 4 suits with 13 cards per suit. I feel like I may be looking at this question wrong from the angle of probabilities.  How do I answer this?

Comment: Have you heard of the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: If the puzzle is too hard when you consider general $n$, try it for $n=5$. I deal five cards to you.  Must you have four cards of a single suit?  Must there be three?  Must there be two?

Comment: Yes I've been looking at the chapter on the pigeonhole principle in my book, but I guess I am unsure of how to apply it.  The way I am currently looking at the question is that for set of numbers n where n = n1,n2,...nN that every n has a probability of 1/4 for being a certain suit.

Comment: When you say "must be present" you are not looking at probability-you are looking for the minimum number that can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  if you want the minimum number of matching cards, distribute them as evenly as possible between the suits.